# How to know how much time the player is in air (Roblox)?

Tags: lua, air, touch, roblox

I just created a Roblox game of shooting. The main target of the game is to stay alive as long as possible. But I recently noticed while playing other games that people use mods for flying in air. (In simple words 'hacking').

If the people use that in my game also they might be the one and only winner always.

So I decided to check when a player is not touching any object (In air) for more than 5 seconds the the player should die.

But then I searched In Google if there are any ways that I can do that. But found none. If anyone know how to achieve that can please help me...

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of my 1 minute google search, no idea what you searched for...

From: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Humanoid/FloorMaterial

> When the Humanoid is not standing on a floor, the value of this
> property will be set to Air.
>
> The code sample below demonstrates how to listen to when this property
> changes using [Instance:GetPropertyChangedSignal](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/GetPropertyChangedSignal)

So if the material changed to Air you start a 5 second timer.
If the player lands stop the timer. When the timer finishes, kill the player.

There are some comments that FloorMaterial might be problematic if the player is swimming. So probably use https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Humanoid/StateChanged  to start and stop the timer.

That should give you plenty of starting points. I won't give you any code. Make yourself familiar with the examples and you'll come up with a solution quickly.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time on me, But my question is about the player should not touch anything, even other players, objects of the game, water  etc

Comment: well then stop the timer on collisions as well. I thought you could make that small step yourself. maybe you should spend some time with the roblox manual. if you don't know what can be done, how can you come up with solutions?

Comment: Well I'm still learning roblox studio and all these projects are just for my practice. I learn from youtube. I never saw the roblox manual. If possible could you please share the link for the manual ( if you are free).

Comment: My answer contains multiple links to the manual. you don't learn anything from blindly following tutorials. always make sure you refer to the manual for everything you use in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your support and suggestions. 